# How to inject a context to the function constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, security

As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!), I've used function constructor in order to avoid `evil` method. Didn't find a better way to inject the context:

```
  function evalContext(context: Record<string, unknown>) {
    const injectContext = Object.keys(context).reduce(
      (acc, key) => `${acc}${key}=context.${key};`,
      '',
    );
    return Function(`context`, `${injectContext}${script}`)(context);
  }

  const handleKeyDown: KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement> = useEventCallback((event) => {
    if (event.code === 'KeyE' && event.metaKey) {
      evalContext({ a: 3, b: 4, log: console.log });
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
```

[image]

Still, it works (no need to prefix the keys with `this`). The main question is would it be possible to "hide" browser objects (window, document, location, ...). From the aspect of security, the script used in the function constructor will be visible only to the owner of the account. Hope this is safe.

As a side question, tried to use a few code editor libs: monaco-editor, react-simple-code-editor, @uiw/react-textarea-code-editor, @patternfly/react-code-editor... Haven't managed to run any of them (broken this, broken that in the next.js context). Please could you suggest any of them that works fine in the most recent version on NJS?

*Update:*

Based on @kelly's suggestion:

```
  function evalContext(context: Record<string, unknown>) {
    const injectContext = Object.keys(context).reduce(
      (acc, key) => `${acc}${key}=context.${key};`,
      '',
    );
    return Function(
      'context',
      'window',
      'document',
      'location',
      'localStorage',
      'navigation',
      'fetch',
      'frames',
      'history',
      `(function () {${injectContext}${script}}).call({})`,
    )(context);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to only ask one question in, well, a question. Ask other questions in their own separate questions. However, your side question is asking for recommendations; we don't give recommendations for software/libraries as answers.

Comment: If you have a specific answer it's best to put that as an answer, rather than as part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could just "override" the global names by adding parameters:

```
return Function(`context`, `window`, `globalThis`, `document`, ..., `${injectContext}${script}`)(context, undefined, undefined, undefined, ...);
```

Similar to this example:

```
function overridden(window) {
    window.open("site");
}

overridden(undefined); // error will occur
```

Since not providing the parameter is *basically* the same as providing `undefined`, you can omit the `undefined` entirely:

```
return Function(`context`, `window`, `globalThis`, `document`, ..., `${injectContext}${script}`)(context);
```

Keep in mind that there are a *lot* of things in the global namespace.

`Object.keys(window)` will give you an idea...